# How do I pass multiple objects to the Rails controller action "create" via JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, knockout.js

As you can probably tell by this question, I am a newbie to both Ruby on Rails and Knockout.

I'm trying to build a RoR web app that will allow a user to pull up their assets data which is stored in a MySQL database, edit that data using Knockout on the front end, and then use Knockout to send the revised data back to the server via Ajax to Rails.

At this URL here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html
it says:

```
The convention in Rails is that, when you pass into an action a JSON object 
graph, the framework can automatically convert it to an ActiveRecord object 
graph and then save it to your database. It knows which of the objects are 
already in your database, and issues the correct INSERT or UPDATE statements.
```

I've tried doing Google searches and I haven't found anything that makes it clear to a newbie like myself.  So I'm asking this question here.

In Knockout.js, when the user submits, they will be triggering a function "saveAssets" which will send the data in JSON format to "/assets" on the Rails app.  The idea is that "self.assets()" will contain multiple instances of Asset objects.

```
self.saveAssets = function() {
    $.ajax('/assets', {
        data: ko.toJSON({ assets: self.assets() }),
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function() { console.log('hella') }
    });
};
```

When that function executes, here is the JSON that gets posted to the Rails server.  Most of the Asset objects have id values, which means they are already in the server and I just want to update them, but there's also one new Asset record without an id number:

```
{"assets": [
  {"id":1,"desc":"DWS Investments Roth IRA Mutual Fund","shares":"810.577","symbol":"SCQGX","price":"41.17","total":"33371.46"},
  {"id":2,"desc":"DWS Investments Money Market Fund","shares":"20000.00","symbol":null,"price":1,"total":"20000.00"},
  {"id":6,"desc":"credit card debt","shares":"-8700.00","symbol":null,"price":1,"total":"-8700.00","_destroy":true},
  {"shares":"0.00","symbol":"","price":1,"total":"0.00"}
]}
```

And here's the Ruby on Rails controller action code:

```
def create  
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {
      @assets = params[:assets]
      @assets.each do |this_asset|
        @a = Asset.new(this_asset)
        @a.save
      end
    }
  end
end
```

What am I supposed to be doing in the "create" action in order to receive the JSON array, parse it into individual "Asset" objects and save/update them to the database?

Thanks for your help!